# Boundary of slice disk exterior is the zero surgery of slice knot

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, knot-theory

I'm trying to understand a sketch of proof of Livingston and Naik's draft book [Introduction to Knot Concordance](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/naik/ConcordanceBook.pdf) which is displayed in the following picture.

[image]

Using some general topological identities, I couldn't follow why

$\partial X(D) = (\partial B^4 - (Int(N(D)) \cap \partial B^4)) \cup
    (\partial N(D) \cap Int(B^4))$ ?

$\partial N(D) = (D \times \partial B^2) \cup (\partial D \times B^2)$ implies $\overline{\partial N(D) \cap Int(B^4)} = D \times B^2$ ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you are taking out a neighbourhood of a Disk which intersecting the the boundary along a knot, then you are taking out a nbd of the knot from the bounday, but the interior of the disk helps you to add some more part in the torus boundary of the knot(which is 0 surgery essentially). Try to draw two dimensional analogous pic,.ie, start with a square and see what happen if you take out a nbd of an arc which intersect the bounday at exactly two points. Also if you are famalier with Kirby calculus, try to recall cancelling 1-2 pairs and dotted circle notation.(Gompf and Stipsicz page 168)

Comment: I’m familiar with handlebody analogue of the proof. I’m just curious about this point-set topological proof.